# Buscar elemento de um dicionário pelo Gherkin

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Necessito realizar uma automação, na qual necessito que o meu código faça uma leitura das informações apresentadas na **Tabela do Gherkin** para que selecione a opção que apresentei dentro de um dicionário, que está em um arquivo destinado ao Page Object.

Estou com o Gherkin, escrito da seguinte maneira:

Quando selecionar os campos

| Buttons |
| --- |
| buttonOne |
| buttonTwo |
| buttonFour |

No Page Object, possuo uma função para armazenar as informações, no qual os campos estão com seus locators, dentro de um dicionário, como abaixo:

```
def func(self):    
dicionario = {    
"Op 1": self.botao_op1    
"Op 2": self.botao_op2    
"Op 6": self.botao_op6        
}
self.dicionario[**Como definir aqui um parametro que irá buscar a informação descrita na tabela do Gherkin**].click()
```

O meu step, está da seguinte maneira:

```
@when('Quando selecionar os campos')
def insert_items_profile(context):
  context.page_object.dicionario()
```

**Como fazer com que na execução, leia a informação do meu código, que passe para função dentro do Page Object?**

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.